# How can I be more clear about this concept?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155942/5254963) here has received a few downvotes I suspect because people think I'm wrong (my total reputation for the answer is 24). It's made obvious by this guy's deal

> C++ has graphics, it is terminal that doesnt support displaying
>   images. This is not language issue.

This is simply false!! The language itself doesn't provide graphics. Third party libraries do that. Everyone else's focus on the terminal (something that C++ doesn't even care about) will completely misconceptualize the OP's mind. Maybe there is a terminal that supports graphics that requires a special API. Whatever, it's not C++'s job.

Issue is, I can't get any more clear than "C++ has no graphics library." That's the truth, full stop. Is there ways to improve my answer?

Comment: 4 upvotes and 2 downvotes makes `+36` not 24.

Comment: @MartinSmith It has been upvoted since I posted this. I see +30 in my profile!!

Answer (score 9):

Ignoring the correctness of the answer, I see 2 more problems that could be contributing to downvotes.

First, take out the fluff, you answer is effectively "C++ doesn't do that".  While it may be correct<sup>1</sup>, it really is not super helpful.  Ok, so C++ doesn't do it, how would you suggest the OP try to solve his problem?

Which leads to the 2nd issue. You answered an extremely vague (and broad) question. Rather than rushing to answer a bad question, you should stop and try to figure out exactly what the asker wants so you can provide an answer that is truly helpful and is not a guess.

If the question was more clear, you could have provided a better answer that says "C++ doesn't do that, but here is how you can accomplish what you are trying to do...."

<sup>1 - I can't speak to the actually accuracy of your answer, so for the purpose of this question, I am working under the assumption your are correct</sup>

Comment: It is not fluff!! The question is "Is there any way to print an image in on console screen using C/C++ commands?" The answer is "No", full stop. Unfortunately if the OP wants library recommends they can use google

Comment: Suggesting how the OP 'try to solve his problem' is lurching dangerously towards recommending a graphics library.   It's almost inevitable that 'you need a graphics library' would be followed by 'which one do you suggest I use' and 40 posts about how great/crap OpenGL is.

Comment: @MartinJames so, recommending a library in an answer does not make an answer bad or make the question off-topic.  If a library is the answer to the question, there are ways to make an acceptable answer by recommending a library.  But again, part of the problem is the vague question.  Lack of clarity is a big contributor to the problem

Comment: I agree with the analysis here and think that helping the question be a better question should always be something we try to do. I also noticed one more thing that may make people want to downvote your answers more than other users answers. Your username. This is an opinion of mine, but in combination with your fluff, and what some might see as a temper (No!!), your status as a new user and the use of a username that is not your real name really sets people on the downvote path. I don't think it's right, I'm just saying that this could be an additional problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem in communication. So when you say that :

> C++ has no graphics library.

This is actually an ambiguous statement at best. And most English speakers understand this differently than what you're trying to say. Reword it to say that "  the C++ standard  doesn't support graphics natively "

C++ does indeed  have graphics library. [A number of them.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs)

and that's what Luka said I think:

> C++ has graphics, it is terminal that doesnt support displaying
>   images. This is not language issue.

He's right, not a language issue.

This post has 2 upvotes. It is not a very thorough answer. This is really not quite what StackOverflow considers "answer" mateiral. More of a comment really.

Comment: The question is ""Is there any way to print an image in on console screen using C/C++ commands?" This is a yes or no answer. Is it a comment instead of an answer because you disagree with "no" as an answer?

Comment: BTW none of the libraries in that link cover graphics in the terminal. The only relevant one cwidget is for UI elements.

Comment: I really think that the way he has answered the problem along with his anonymous username and status as a new user all help to contribute to others downvoting. Does nobody else think that is a valid point? even if his answer is right, it's like.. not the right attitude for an answer?

Comment: @user5254963 It's not yes/no. Did you ever hear about ASCII art?